# How to search unresolved libraries in Intellij IDEA or Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm trying to port [Apache Flink](http://flink.apache.org) to Android. One of the biggest problem is that some java tools doesn't exist for Android, but these conflict are not detected at compile time and the errors (`NoClassDefFoundError` excpetion) are detected only at runtime.

For example, Java's [ManagementFactory](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/management/ManagementFactory.html) doesn't exists for android, BUT no compile error is thrown even if in [this](https://github.com/apache/flink/blob/c08bcf1e008397bfe22353e3ba3d9d9656e7d3c1/flink-runtime/src/main/java/org/apache/flink/runtime/taskmanager/MemoryLogger.java) class there are unresolved symbols/libraries, in particular:

```
import javax.management.MBeanServer;

import java.lang.management.BufferPoolMXBean;
import java.lang.management.GarbageCollectorMXBean;
import java.lang.management.ManagementFactory;
import java.lang.management.MemoryMXBean;
import java.lang.management.MemoryPoolMXBean;
import java.lang.management.MemoryType;
import java.lang.management.MemoryUsage;
```

Now, I included the Flink's jars (flink-clients, flink-java, flink-runtime and flink-streaming) in my Android Studio project and I would like to search all these kind of unresolved dependencies to avoid these kind of exception at runtime. There is any Android Studio tool for this purpose?

Comment: add -info to build.It will show some message about reflect method.

Comment: After your comment I added `-info` but no useful information is returned.

Comment: Are you sure it's an android project?

Comment: I don't see how working on Android Studio could not be an android project. Anyway, yes, 101% sure that this is an Android Project, and adding `-info` to `File->Settings->Build, Execution, Deployment->Compiler->Command-line Options` didn't returned anything useful to detect unresolved libraries.

Comment: Can you uplaod your project to github?

Comment: Not possible: the repository is private for university policy. Anyway, you can ask me what you need and I'll eventually post it here.

Comment: I don't think a sample need any policy,You can just upload a demo, not your real project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think including jar dependencies in the project will not make Android Studio and a compiler to search for missing classes in already built jars. Try to include src of flink into your project. I tried that and I had all unresolved imports being red.

Comment: This could be a solution, but what if there is a 3rd party library used in flink src that relies on some unresolved library?

Comment: I guess you have to find them and include them also as a src, because java for android is slightly different from regular java, and these 3rd party libraries could also have classes that are not in SDK.

Comment: I guess that's the only solution (hell on earth)